# How to navigate Android C++ sources

Tags: android, c++, android-source

I'm interested how Android starts activities, and how exactly the fade-in animation is implemented when starting an activity.

I can navigate the Java sources easily e.g. on GrepCode, and found out there's a way to override the activity transition, which brought me to [IActivityManager.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/IActivityManager.java#319) which defines:

```
public int startActivities(
  IApplicationThread caller, String callingPackage, ...);
```

And also:

```
public void overridePendingTransition(
  IBinder token, String packageName, int enterAnim, int exitAnim);
```

Both of these call into native code using RPC constants such as:

```
int START_ACTIVITIES_TRANSACTION = IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION+120;
```

My question is: Where can I find the actual C++ code where `startActivities` and `overridePendingTransition` are implemented?

Google returns nothing and it looks like the AOSP codebase is spread across multiple Git repos (?) and don't know which one to look into.

In general, how do you navigate from a Java interface to a C++ implementation of that interface?

Comment: tried http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/ ?

Comment: Thanks! That gets me to this Java file but don't know what C++ code gets called from there: http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java#3100

Comment: Randomly guessed and searched for windowEnterTransition. This gives me something interesting: http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/search?q=windowentertransition&defs=&refs=&path=.+xml&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=toolchain&project=tools

Comment: is it what you want? http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/search?q=&defs=&refs=&path=ActivityManagerService.java&hist=&project=frameworks, also, just wild guess...

Comment: windowEnterAnimation and activityOpenEnterAnimation also look promising.

Comment: This is probably the animation when switching apps, not switching Activities, but also interesting: http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/AppTransition.java

Comment: I think I found it!
http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/activity_open_enter.xml

Comment: so you dont need c++ implementation nor `Binder` implementaion but rather xml code... what a dramatic change of narration ;-)

Comment: Yes I found what I was looking for by realizing the animation might be defined in a resource and then trying random words. But still don't know how to jump from a Java interface to a C++ implementation. Won't need that for now but would be awesome to know still, for future reference and for others.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the awesome androidxref website!

Comment: you are welcome, for a a native code, lets take `Matrix` for example: see [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Matrix.java#456)  then for `native_postTranslate` select "all projects" and use "Full search" (first edit text), you will find /frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Matrix.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding methods are implemented in `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java`. Go to this file and you will find the implementation of your methods.

Such unusual location is explained by the following. In case of the ActivityManagerService, the Binder interface is implemented manually, without using .aidl description. The interface `IActivityManager.java` is implemented by the abstract class `ActivityManagerNative` in `ActivityManagerNative.java`, the actual implementation of which is actually provided in the `ActivityManagerService.java`.